# could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) PostgreSQL

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services, nginx

I using AWS and want to connect postgresql but i have the problem

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "xx.xxx.x.x" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

On server stay ubuntu 18.04, i installed postgres 
used this command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "local all all trust" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf'
sudo sh -c 'echo "host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf'
sudo sh -c 'echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf'
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Yes i deleted '#'

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxxxxx:~$ sudo netstat -ltpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6462/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      629/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1040/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20516/postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20539/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16863/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5434            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20517/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      6462/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      5975/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1040/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      16863/master
tcp6       0      0 :::5434                 :::*                    LISTEN      20517/postgres
```

Connecting from pgAdmin4
What i didn't right? Thanks for answering
if i used commands i showed

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxxx:~$ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@ip-xxxxxxxx:~$ psql
psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
```

Comment: This is a network problem. Perhaps you used the wrong host name or port. Perhaps there is a firewall that blocks TCP connections.

Comment: any proxy settings?

Comment: i using free tire AWS service EC2, Instance type - t2.micro. How i can check proxy settings, i do that. Maybe it because i installed 3 versions of postgresql 
https://prnt.sc/sat2hh

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe https://prnt.sc/sat7cl

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated the security groups for your RDS instance?
Is the RDS instance in a public or private subnet?
Is it a internal or external RDS instance.

Need some additional network setup to accurately identify, however, from the information provided it cannot connect.

Comment: Security group wise thats fine. From reading it seems like you're running it on EC2.

Ubuntu 18.04 comes preinstalled with IP Tables. Have you configured it to enable external access to the world?

Comment: configure ubuntu or postgres on ubuntu? I have configured like that
 ```sudo sh -c 'echo "local all all trust" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf'
sudo sh -c 'echo "host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf'
sudo sh -c 'echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/bg_hba.conf'```

Comment: Try running `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 000.000.000.000  --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT`.

Its possibly IP tables which is restricting this

Comment: i deleted all postgresql 9, 10 , 12 
using ```sudo apt-get purge postgresql-x.x``` reinstall using ```sudo apt-get install postgresql-12 pgadmin4``` when i want to connect i see ```FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xx.xx.xx", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xx.xx.xx", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off```

Comment: I ran into a problem similar to this. What I found out is that the path that the PostgreSQL install guide showed for the pg_hba.conf file was different than where it actually was located on my machine. Check the file path yourself to determine the correct location of that file on your host server.

Comment: Also make sure to check your postgresql.conf file to ensure listen_addresses is not commented out. I keep mine equal to 0.0.0.0 to allow any external connection, then set up your pg_hba.conf file to specify from what IP addresses connections will be accepted. Keep in mind that if you are adding a rule to this file with specific IP addresses, you need to include the CIDR mask on the end (for example, X.X.X.X/32) otherwise Postgres will still block connections from that IP address.